# Loop children of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the best way to loop through a multidimensional array to return the matching indexed child elements in PHP?

The array will be created dynamically so I will not know the count. Every item will have a pair, even if it is just an empty string.

**Sample array:**

```
array(1) {
  ["gallery"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["img"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "first"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "second"
    }
    ["test"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "one"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "two"
    }
  }
}
```

**Desired result:**

first one

second two

Comment: Have you even tried something ?

Comment: May there be more elements than `img` and `test` as well as multiple child elements of those?

Comment: Have you done your basic as well as have you check the array section in php manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code for desired output

```
<?php
$array = array('gallery' => array("img" => array("first", "second"), "test" => array("one", "two")));
//var_dump($array);
foreach($array as $arr) {
   for($i=0;$i<count($arr['img']);$i++)
   {
       echo $arr['img'][$i].' '.$arr['test'][$i].'<br />';
   }
}
?>
```

let me know any further help needed

Comment: wont let me for another 1 minute but will do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MultipleIterator<sup>[PHP.net]</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) class for this:

```
$array = array(
    'gallery' => array(
        "img"  => array("first", "second"),
        "test" => array("one",   "two")
    )
);

$it1 = new ArrayIterator($array['gallery']['img']);
$it2 = new ArrayIterator($array['gallery']['test']);

$multipleIterator = new MultipleIterator();
$multipleIterator->attachIterator($it1);
$multipleIterator->attachIterator($it2);

foreach ($multipleIterator as $pair) {
    echo $pair[0], " ", $pair[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
first one
second two
```

For newer PHP versions you may also use `list` in the foreach:

```
foreach ($multipleIterator as list($img, $test)) {
    echo $img, " ", $test, PHP_EOL;
}
```